# Internal Server Error (Timeou waiting for output from CGI)

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, wordpress

All,

I'll admit right away that I'm not very familiar with the server side of things, just FYI, so I'm not sure how to debug this error. I moved my website from a Windows platform to an Linux platform and a new VPS. I'm getting an "Internal Sever Error" every once in awhile and I'm not sure why. When I look at the server logs I'm seeing this:

"Timeout waiting for output from CGI script /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper"

I'm running WordPress for my sites. Can someone tell me how to debug this error? Sometimes the site works fine which is really strange. Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you post some relevant info from the Apache config (depending on how you've done the config, the bits describing the relevant site which is failing).

Comment: Tony,I have the base configuration, I haven't done anything to it. I'll try to get the config and post it. I'm getting a permission denied error trying to get it so I have to contact the host.

Comment: You'll want to show apache and error log info as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what you would like to see?                           <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
 FcgidInitialEnv PP_CUSTOM_PHP_INI /var/www/vhosts/pvcob.com/etc/php.ini
</IfModule>
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/vps-1094557-8985.manage.myhosting.com/httpdocs>
<Files ~ (\.php)>
 SetHandler None
 AddHandler php-script .php
 Options +ExecCGI
 allow from all
</Files>

Comment: Log: [Wed May 16 13:02:16 2012] [warn] [client 157.55.116.28] Timeout waiting for output from CGI script /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper
[Wed May 16 13:03:31 2012] [error] [client 206.18.168.224] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/sqlite.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Wed May 16 13:03:52 2012] [error] [client 206.18.168.224] Premature end of script headers: cgi_wrapper

Comment: @JMac you should add that information to your question, rather than include it in the comments where it's hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is trying to use PHP's sqlite module, but it's not installed.  You don't say which Linux distribution you're using so I can't comment on how to install it, but that's where you should start looking.

Comment: I'll look into that first.

Comment: All, not sure if it means anything but in my suexec_log I'm seeing: uid: (10000/chadbh) gid: (506/506) cmd: cgi_wrapper